# Meta-analyses for variance rather than means

Tags: r, variance, references, meta-analysis

What are the main complications / differences when conducting a meta-analyses where the metric of focus is not effect size (i.e., means) per se, but instead estimates of variances from models?

Nods to literature are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you can perform a meta-analysis for almost everything. The key point is to be able to refrain from using its results inappropriately. Accordingly, you can pool variances, for sure, but why so, and how?

There can be cases in which you want to focus on variability of an instrument rather than on its average effect, as primary feature to choose it, so using the variance might make sense.

Yet, how can you weigh appropriately each study as the variance is already used as main effect? You could weigh by sample size, possibly. Otherwhise, you could simply build a linear model in which study variance is the dependend variable and study size and study effects are independent variables.

I would like to see the actual application, though. It would be an interesting test to the strenght and robustness of meta-analytic approaches.